# Kentico v9 javascript webpart and bottom load LinkedFile

Tags: kentico

In building on a previous question ([Kentico v9 how can i detect when a user is in CMS desk with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060471/kentico-v9-how-can-i-detect-when-a-user-is-in-cms-desk-with-javascript/36060613#36060613)), I have added a JavaScript webpart to load in my analytics.js file. Here's my code snippet:

```html
      <cms:JavaScript ID="js"
        ViewMode="LiveSite"
        LinkedFile="~/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=/KFF/global/scripts/analytics.js" 
        LinkedFilePageLocation="beginning"
        runat="server"></cms:JavaScript>
```

I can not figure out how to get this to load the JS file at the bottom of the page. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linked File Page Location is the key.  There's one that renders it wherever the webpart is placed.  You need to add a Web Part Zone at the bottom of the page and add them there, or if this is pure aspx then add this tag near the bottom, but the LInkedFilePageLocation should be Inline (i believe, see what the options are)

EDIT

The proper value is "startup" to make it render wherever you place it.

Comment: setting LinkedFilePageLocation="startup" seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Yup that looks like it (looking at the javascript.ascx control)

Comment: I was digging in there, didn't think startup meant that location. Good to know for next time.